# Insert text into text area of Joomla editor

Tags: joomla, editor, textarea

i can't insert text into text area of `JFactory::getEditor()`.

```
$("textarea").val('some text');
```

can't update text area in my dom.

If i use a default `<textarea>` it work fine.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
   <fieldset addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_categories/models/fields" >

        <field
                type="editor"
                name="myEditorField"
                id="myEditorField"
                label="MY EDITOR FIELD LABEL"
                description="MY EDITOR FIELD DESCRIPTION"
                width= "99%"
                rows="5"
                editor="desired|alternative"
                cols="200"
                buttons="true"/>
                <field name="articletext" type="editor" class="inputbox"
        label="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_ARTICLETEXT_LABEL"     description="COM_CONTENT_FIELD_ARTICLETEXT_DESC"
        filter="JComponentHelper::filterText" buttons="true" />

   </fieldset>


</form>
```

save above code in editor.xml and use following php code to display editor

```
<?php
        $mypath=  JPATH_COMPONENT.'/views/' .'createTask'. '/tmpl/editor.xml';
        $form = JForm::getInstance('myform',$mypath );
        echo $form->getInput('myEditorField');
?>
```

follwoing code will echo javascript to set editor content

```
$editor =JFactory::getEditor();
$setContent=$editor->setContent($name,'hello');

$js1 = 'function setEditorText (){return '.$setContent.'}';
$doc=  JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js1);
```

for details [click here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/how-tos/development/getting-started-with-jform/)

.
.
.
.

Other way to get and set content in JOOMLA editor is use following js.

Wrap your editor in div having class .myPreviewEditor
to set content

```
$('.myPreviewEditor iframe').contents().find('body').html("i am in editor");
```

to get content

```
$editoContent=$('.myPreviewEditor iframe').contents().find('body').html();
```

but make sure that these statement execute after JOOMLA editor loads itself

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to use the `setContent` function in a way that lets you set the content in the javascript and not in the php? Just use a `.replace()`?

Comment: when i was in quest of same question that you are asking, what i found was that joomla editor loads in iframe so it may not be possible to use php or may be a bit complex to achieve desired results optimally. . . . so i opted js and left that quest